# Boundary in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I should prove or give a counterexample for:

$\partial (\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i) \subset \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (\partial A_i)$

Where $\partial$ is the boundary and (X,d) is a metric space with $A_{i} \subset X $ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$

I cannot make up a counterexample for finite sets $A_{i}$ but I think there might be one for infinite ones, or am I wrong?

Comment: @User3123: Your $U_{i}$ should be $A_{i}$ i think

Comment: Yep, I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ and the sets $A_i = \{\frac{1}{i}\}$.
the boundary of $\bigcup A_i = \{\frac{1}{i} \mid i\in \mathbb{N}\}=A$ is $A\cup \{0\}$ while $\partial A_i = A_i$ so $\bigcup \partial A_i = A $

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \{ 1/i , i \in \mathbb N \}$ considered as a metric sub-space of $\mathbb R$. Let $A_i = \{ 1/i\}$. The RHS is empty whereas LHS is the set $\{ 0\}$.